# Simple proof to find minimum $P=(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)$

Tags: inequality, uvw

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=abc+2.$ Find the minimum$$P=(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)$$By $a=b=c=1,$ we will prove $P\ge 8$ or $$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge 8.$$
After full expanding, it remains to prove $$(abc)^2+a^3+b^3+c^3+(ab)^3+(bc)^3+(ca)^3\ge 7$$We can replace the condition but it leads to something complicated.

I hope to see more simple ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

Generally, we'll prove the following inequality$$abc+\sqrt[3]{(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)}\ge ab+bc+ca, \tag{*}$$holds for all $a,b,c\ge 0.$

WLOG, by Dirichlet rule we can assume that $(b-1)(c-1)\ge 0.$

It implies$$a(b-1)(c-1)\ge 0\iff abc+a+bc\ge ab+bc+ca.$$Now, using Minkowski on $(*)$ \begin{align*}
    abc+\sqrt[3]{(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)}&=abc+\sqrt[3]{(a^3+1)(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}\\& \ge abc+\sqrt[3]{a^3}+\sqrt[3]{(bc)^3}\\&= abc+a+bc\ge ab+bc+ca.
\end{align*}
Thus, the proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=c=1.$

About Minkowski inequality, see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Minkowski_Inequality)

Comment: Nice! You used the known inequality.

Comment: @TATAbox How did Holder work ?

Comment: @Dragonboy I fixed it. See now

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Did you mean $$abc+\sqrt[3]{(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)}\ge ab+bc+ca, \tag{*}$$ ?

Comment: @TATAbox Now it is clear. Good one

Comment: @TATAbox (*) is nice.

Comment: By "Dirichlet rule" you mean "pigeonhole principle" on the two possibilities of signs for each of  ({a,b,c} - 1), correct?